# Why is flex box not working even in chrome?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<style type="text/css" href="style.css"></style>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Magic Notes</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <form class="d-flex">
                    <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container my-3 mx-10" style="max-width:70vw;margin:0 auto;">
        <h1>Welcome To Magic Notes</h1>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Add a Note</h5>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="addTxt" style="height: 100px"></textarea>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top:1em;"" id= " addBtn">Add Note</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <h1>Your Notes</h1>
        <hr>
        <div class="container">
            <div>HI</div>
            <div>HI</div>
            <div>HI</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Atwg2Pkwv9vp0ygtn1JAojH0nYbwNJLPhwyoVbhoPwBhjQPR5VtM2+xf0Uwh9KtT"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- <script src="app.js"></script> -->
</body>
```

In the code below I have used very little CSS just to experiment with some things(I will be adding the CSS file below). However, My target class container is not showing stuff horizontally even after changing it to flex. I have used some bootstrap classes and am very new to this stuff what is the possible reason for this incomprehensible behavior.

The CSS code:

```
*{
margin:0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;}

.container{
display:flex;
flex-direction:row;
flex: 1;}
```

Comment: I know that this is kinda silly, but have you already tried to Ctrl + F5? Because, I tested the code, and it's horizontal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<style type="text/css" href="style.css"></style>
```

This is your problem. When connecting your CSS file, you need to use a link tag instead of a style tag. Try this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```